# Getting Oauth token error while executing azcopy

Tags: azure-powershell

I have the below command to copy folders and its sub directories to blob storage. I am using the 10.3.4 version.
azcopy copy \uncserver\source1\folder1\archive https://1234server.blob.core.windows.net/folder2/target/archive/ --recursive

Am getting the below error while executing the above command. I know, am executing without SAS token. but it should regonize the OAuth token. 
I want to go with Oauth token. How do I proceed further.

Error:
failed to perform copy command due to error: no sas token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the SAS token, there are a number of people who ran into Oauth token errors that were generated because the session key ring was not propagated/shared in the expected way.  The workaround for this (other than using a SAS token), is to switch to a named session key ring instead of the default:

Check your AzCopy Key:

```
keyctl show
```

Switch to a named session key ring:

```
keyctl session workaroundSession
```

After this, AzCopy should work as normal.

**Reference:**

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/452#issuecomment-503812803
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/819